# how to solve the -[__NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance when application terminates?

Tags: iphone, ios

hi all i have implemented code as shown in the below but when run this code it is terminating and showing exception in below how to handle the exception to get the latitude and longitude in iphone

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress: (NSString *) address
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D myLocation; 



    NSString *esc_addr = [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];

    NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];

    NSDictionary *resultsDict = [googleResponse valueForKey:  @"results"];
    NSDictionary *geometryDict = [resultsDict valueForKey: @"geometry"];     
    NSDictionary *locationDict = [geometryDict valueForKey: @"location"];       
    NSArray *latArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lat"]; 
    NSString *latString = [latArray lastObject];   
    NSArray *lngArray = [locationDict valueForKey: @"lng"];
    NSString *lngString = [lngArray lastObject];    

    myLocation.latitude = [latString doubleValue];     
    myLocation.longitude = [lngString doubleValue];

    NSLog(@"lat: %f\tlon:%f", myLocation.latitude, myLocation.longitude);
    return myLocation;
}
```

Error from the console:

```
[1055:11603] -[__NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xabcc200
[1055:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xabcc200'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x16ee052 0x13d9d0a 0x16efced 0x1654f00 0x1654ce2 0x25a5 0x248f 0x16efec9 0x3945c2 0x39455a 0x439b76 0x43a03f 0x4392fe 0x3b9a30 0x3b9c56 0x3a0384 0x393aa9 0x1de4fa9 0x16c21c5 0x1627022 0x162590a 0x1624db4 0x1624ccb 0x1de3879 0x1de393e 0x391a9b 0x1dcd 0x1d45)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: hi when i am running the program automatically terminating my application and it is giving  message like

Comment: Couldn't register com.yourcompany.SimpleMapView with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(lldb)

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to include your json library and the `NSString` JSONValue category is missing.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in the development version. Try using a stable version [from here](https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads)

Answer (score -1):

You are basically sending JSONValue message to an NSString instance, that's why your application is crashing, here:

```
NSDictionary *googleResponse = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: req] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL] JSONValue];
```